# My Galaxy i5503 (Android 2.2) is dead, they say it needs new software?

Tags: updates, 2.2-froyo

My phone is not switching on. It's a Samsung Galaxy i5503/Galaxy 5. It started automatic switch offs even on a little pressure and now it's not getting on.

Someone checked it and said they need to reinstall the software (probably the operating system, which is Android 2.2).

My question is: **Can I do it manually? If yes, then how?** And, if I opt for getting it done from someone, **What data will be erased? I cannot afford to lose the data of my applications (like Colornote's notes).**

Comment: 2.2 is pretty old. You might wish to check with our [update tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/update/info) for how to update it, plus [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) on where to obtain the software to "re-install" (more links in our [rom tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info)). What data will be erased depends on the update process, so no "generic" answer on that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have bad news:
It almost impossible to get data from your internal storage if your mobile does not turn on.
First we need to know more about the problem:

What do you mean under not turn on?

Does it light up or no signal at all? What if you plug it into the charger? Can you see any lights flash up? Can you get into recovery?

If none of the above happen, then I need to ask: Is your important data stored on your SD card? Most apps store their user data on SD Card so you can access them if you pull out your SD card and read from that.

If you re-install android, you WILL LOSE your internal data so if you have lots of important things on your phone (not your SD Card) you should not reinstall without backup

Colornote does not store your data internally but uploads to the cloud. See [Their FAQ](http://www.colornote.com/FAQ.html#collapse6)

Comment: It's totally dead, nothing of that happens. Formerly, it used to show charging status, but now, nothing. I understand that most data is stored on SD card, plus I have no problem with contacts, as everything from calendar and contacts is Google-synchronised. For colornote, I saw the options of online sync, but I never opted for that. I have my SD card, maybe colornote has stored something there... I'll have a look.

Comment: Yes it worked! I installed ColorNote on my tablet and inserted my phone's SD card. It was able to backup all the notes! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am happy I could help you! It said auto backup on the website. Also, are there other app datas that you need? Maybe there is a way to get them back.

Comment: My phone's memo application (the inbuilt, default notes making app)... That's all I wish!